# C Program curl: (35) error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure

Tags: c, ssl, curl

I'm trying to make a C program that downloads an image given a url.
However, I can't seem to be able to download from a particular website using libcurl-7.52.1.
When using the curl command on this url gives me:

```
~ $ curl -v https://files.yande.re/jpeg/ae340a06572fa8f48d63fd418197e1cd/yande.re%20292874%20makise_kurisu%20ninnzinn%20pantyhose%20steins%3Bgate.jpg
*   Trying 5.39.10.56...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to files.yande.re (5.39.10.56) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Unknown (21):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS alert, Server hello (2):
* error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 1
* stopped the pause stream!
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure
```

When using my own program with the following code and curl options, I get the same error:

```
FILE *img_fp;
img_fp = fopen(file_name, "wb");

/* Initialize curl */
CURL *curl_handle = curl_easy_init();
CURLcode res;

if (curl_handle) {
    /* set the working website to this domain */
    /* weburl is the url of the website */
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, web_url);

    /* ask libcurl to show us the verbose output */
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);

    /* Set the user agent to chrome */
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "chrome/55.0.2883.75");

    /* Set the data to pass when the function is called */
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, img_fp);

    res = curl_easy_perform(curl_handle);

    /* Check for errors */
    if (res != CURLE_OK) {
        printf("curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
                curl_easy_strerror(res));

    }
}
Output:
*   Trying 5.39.10.56...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to files.yande.re (5.39.10.56) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 1
* stopped the pause stream!
* Closing connection 0
curl_easy_perform() failed: SSL connect error
```

How can I fix this and download the file?

Comment: It is probably a problem with your TLS library. That same URL works fine for me with that curl version using GnuTLS/3.5.7 or OpenSSL/1.1.0c

Comment: Wow, thanks! I recompiled curl to use GnuTLS-3.4.17 and it is working remarkably. I guess it doesn't work with anything <Openssl-1.1.0c

Comment: @Kamiyaa: GnuTLS and OpenSSL are different implementations of TLS, i.e. curl uses only one of these at a time. Thus succeeding with a specific GnuTLS version says nothing about which OpenSSL version might work.  Your question missing information which GnuTLS or OpenSSL version is used in the original curl (check `curl -V`) but my guess it was one with no support for ECDHE because the site requires ECDHE.

Comment: My curl was previously compiled with openssl-1.0.2j. But in the repositories of the distribution I'm using, OpenSSL-1.1.0 is labelled as unstable currently. So I opted to compile curl with GnuTLS.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably a problem with your TLS library. That same URL works fine for me with that curl version using GnuTLS/3.5.7 or OpenSSL/1.1.0c – Daniel Stenberg

I recompiled curl to use GnuTLS-3.4.17 and it is working remarkably. I guess it doesn't work with anything <Openssl-1.1.0c – Kamiyaa